# Generic function type with named propery as second parameter

Tags: typescript, jsx, tsx, solid-js

Is it possible to create a generic component function such that a prop of it will be accessible in the generic type and guaranteed to be of a specific type?

```
type GenericPropType = {
    type: T,
    displayProp: string
}

export function GenericComponent<T>(props: GenericPropType<T>){
    return (<div>{props.type[props.displayProp]}</div>);
}
```

This code will not get through typescripts type validation as the type is not known to have a property displayProps and if it has it is not guaranteed to be of a string | JSXElement type and can not be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you want to enforce `displayProp` to be a key of `type`?

This is easily achievable with:

```js
import React from 'react'

type GenericPropType<T extends string> = {
    type: Record<string, any>&Record<T, React.ReactNode>,
    displayProp: T
}

export function GenericComponent<T extends string>(props: GenericPropType<T>){
    return <div>{props.type[props.displayProp]}</div>;
}

<GenericComponent type={{k:<div></div>, asd:"12313", oouh:123, kajgo:[] }} displayProp="k" />
```

Changes:

1. Made `GenericPropType` actually generic.
2. Added the constraint on `GenericComponent` so that `T` can only be a string. And make the type of `type` such that it's an object and the key `displayKey` exists on `type` and the corresponding value can be rendered.

The neat part is you even get autocomplete when passing the prop.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAcSQDskpg0AFHMAFWqQB5ucJAA8YTACYBnOFJitGAcwB8cALxwA3qTi64VGgC5ESNNAn85CxQBo4KRpWUAyZGagXud5OhgA6HwwAOQgJJGUbHT0JYCkwABsUSk4IMGNuUgBfclFIWDhMAFdGDGAIRnomFjYAYVxIZkYYQWExSRkrYCVlAAowLiljBmZWDi5eGkFlAEptPTgiGEKoCv4YgDdlTX7UqT8DJABtHbA9mLjE5K4AXUz+AHoN5QBuLNJ+ZSjdfmHqtDrwOUmPADmpNJoANaGNbATYPJ52FBSCSGABEAEYAEwAZnR2NRdggEEKAAtDFjsXYISgAFaKCCGQ7XOCZTJwc4JJIpMBqVEQ1Fwe6feY-KqjAENYH6PhgzT2ZFoil4glwImk8k4qm0+mM5ms9mxTlXVK8-mC4V6UUjWr1IFNaU0WVQzSZREKjE45WE4lkilaukMpkstkcy7c00CoXvIVAA)

Comment: This almost solves my use case but it restricts the generic type to only have properties of string... What I need is to be able to send in a complex object where on of the properties can be targeted as the display property and only that property needs to be of the type string.

Comment: Does `Record<string, any>` work?

Comment: No, any is not a type that can be rendered by Jsx. I need to restrict that one property to a string och JsxElement.

Comment: I've edited the answer, you should edit your question to include these requirements

Comment: It's part of the question and your answer is still targeting all properties in the generic type. Enforcing all properties of the generic type to be string or Jsx elements is not the goal. The question states the issue of targeting 1 property to serve as display property and to force that property to exist and conform to the render requirements of Jsx. I do appreciate your proposed solution but it doesn't solve the problem without heavy restrictions on the generic type.

Comment: Check the code I added in the last edit. I think it meets all your requirements. 1. does not restrict all values in the object to one type, 2. the key passed as `displayKey` is required in the `type` prop, 3. since `type[displayKey]` is required to be a ReactNode, it can be rendered without issues.

Comment: i've added a playground link as well

Comment: It might be that react is more accepting with it's node type but I'm not using react. When specifying the second record type as Record<T, string|JSXElement> that doesn't mach my complex objects type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252226/discussion-between-nullptr-and-moriya)?

Answer (score 0):

Solid's Component type is already a generic, you can wrap it in another generic if you like:

```js
import { Component } from 'solid-js';

interface Props<Other = undefined> {
  displayProp: string;
  other: Other;
}

const A: Component<Props<undefined>> = (props) => {
  return <div>{props.displayProp}</div>
};
```

Now type system forces you to use the correct type:

```js
<A displayProp='Hello' other={undefined} />
```

Edit: Reqirement is `displayProp` to be a property on the `other` so that  `props.other[props.displayProp]` returns a value.

```js
import { Component } from 'solid-js';

interface Props {
  color: string;
}

type Other<T> =  { displayProp: string; } & T;

const A: Component<{ other: Other<Props> }> = (props) => {
  return <div>{props.other['displayProp']}</div>
};
```

Now it can be used as:

```js
<A other={{ displayProp: 'color', color: 'red' }} />
```

Comment: This answer does not force the displayProp to be a property on the type Other which was the target of the question. I want to be able to render 
`props.other[props.displayProp]`